# Angular Carousel around div with functionality

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking for a Angular Carousel there is working with Bootstrap divs

I want it to shift between Divs, and I get the next div in center when clicking next or previous.

Bootstrap exsampel til wrap with carousel:

```
<div class="row">
<!-- Carousel start -->
<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-6">
    <div class="box box-lg br-black animated">
        <div class="box-content box-default">
        Functionality 1
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6">
    <div class="box box-lg br-black animated">
        <div class="box-content box-default">
        Functionality 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-6">
    <div class="box box-lg br-black animated">
        <div class="box-content box-default">
        Functionality 3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Carousel end --></div>
```

What possibilities do I have?

Comment: Well, there's `angular-ui` which is angular directives for bootstrap... See [Carousel](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel) here

Comment: The Carousel goes to background when adding the divs.. Do you have a example from a solution?

Comment: if you post a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com) or [plnkr](http://plnkr.co) demonstrating the problem, I can help

Answer (score 1):

your question is a little confused to me. I understood your question but the code show something different. I will try to answer you the question with several alternatives. If you could be more specific with your problem I will help you quickly.

First, there are several carousel for *AngularJS*. There are single libraries that creates carousel, and others like **ui-bootstrap(angular-ui)** and **AngularStrap** that  fit much better with **Twitter Bootstrap**. If you want to use *AngularJS* with **TB**, I recommend you **ui-bootstrap**. I have worked several times with the library and never let me down.

So, creating the carousel with **ui-bootstrap** we have several alternatives. First, to place the content of your `divs` in the center you have not use the grid system obligatory. You can use a single row and center the elements with `text-align`, `margin:0 auto`, `flex model` or others techniques. In this case check the next plunk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/XmzaJx5mXddLQ4S1k7BV

If you want to create each div with columns of the grid system, like your code shown, you have to shift the columns with `.col-md-offset-x`, leaving the same space at the sides. Check the plunk.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ihpwrWC0p64eO1jiddl2

I hope that my answer help you at least a little, If your question is another please, let me know.

Comment: I have tried this and it wooks with ui.bootstrap. Im also using AngularStrap and this is giving problems. AngularStrap dosent have a Carousel.. Im using AngularStrap for a special datepicker mode. AngularStrap and ui.bootstrap combine is not recommended? Can I only use the ui.bootstrap carousel and keep all the AngularStrap?

Comment: The actual sliding stops after one round, and the arrows dont works... Thats next..

Comment: If I want the div to be col-md-10, then the box align wrong. What should the next col be assign to?

Comment: Hi Anders, Did you fix the slide round?, if not post a jsfiddle or plunk to try to help you

Comment: If you want a div with col-md-10 and centered you have to apply "col-md-offset-1". In this case for medium devices resolution the column would shift to the right 1 column, it fill 10 columns and at the right appear the last columns, completing 12 columns.

Comment: Yes. Slide round is fixed. There seems to be a problem with ngAnimate. This is disabled for the slider..

Comment: Fix on slide round:
app.directive('disableAnimation', function ($animate) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                $attrs.$observe('disableAnimation', function (value) {
                    $animate.enabled(!value, $element);
                });
            }
        }
    });

 <carousel interval="myInterval" class="container" disable-animation="true">
<slide>
.......